# XDebug setting responsible for how many elements in arrays and objects to display

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

Currently, in the VSCode environment, in the debug panel, Xdebug only lists 32 elements in arrays and objects. How can I make it echo all elements in the variable?

[image]

Comment: You may have already solved your issue but this question/answer helped me with the same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49752153/visual-studio-code-debugging-array-evaluation

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting the following settings in your `php.ini` file as per your need,

```
[xdebug]
xdebug.var_display_max_data=2048
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=128
xdebug.max_nesting_level=256
```

You can find details on these settings [here](https://xdebug.org/docs/display).
Please note that configuring these settings with higher values may impact the performance.

Comment: I believe these settings are not related to this.